# Change parameters of THREE.tubeGeometry

Tags: javascript, dynamic, three.js

so I have a tube inside my Three.js scene, and I want to dynamically change its start and end points because I think it is cheaper to do that than create a new tube with the new points and remove the old (if it is not tell me why).

this is how I do it: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/22/ press the button.

Obviously I tried to put every attribute related to this to true:

```
grid.dynamic = true;
grid.needsUpdate = true;
grid.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the Hell is this?

```
grid.geometry.parameters.path.points[0]= new THREE.Vector3(1000,100,100);
```

Never seen this before, the geometry of grids dont have something like parameters or am I wrong? You can change the position of the path like the way you created it:

```
var path = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
    new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0) ,
    new THREE.Vector3(200,150,10) 
]);

var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(path, 1, 0.11, 8);
grid.geometry = geometry;
```

Comment: I think it works. It works for the fiddle. I will test it on my project and get back to you. thanks!